# Project reactor: Is there a non-side-effect finally like method (Not the side-effect method doFinally)

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Given such an example:

```
Mono.create(callback -> {
    try { callback.success(someLogic()); }
    catch (Exception e) { callback.error(e); }
   })
   .doFinally((v) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
       Thread.sleep(1000); // In reality, we have a blocking I/O code here and needs to be executed on a separate thread 
   }).block())
   .block();
```

When I run this code, it finishes immediately without waiting for the 1000ms delay. This is because `doFinally` is a side effect method, so it does not execute as part of the chain. Is there a finally like method that can execute as part of the chain?

My current workaround is

```
Mono.create(callback -> {
    try { callback.success(someLogic()); }
    catch (Exception e) { callback.error(e); }
   })
   .then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
   }))
   .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
   }))
   .block();
```

If no such method is there a better approach?

Comment: are you aware that `doFinally` triggers on upstream onComplete/onError signals _but also on downstream `cancel()` signal_? if so, there isn't an operator that delays the cancel signal propagation. if you're only interested in onComplete|onError, then your approach is the recommended one.

Answer (score -1):

`doOnTerminate()` will execute the side-effect before termination.
It does not get the Mono value.

`doOnNext()` will only be called with the value of the Mono, but not on error/cancel.

`tap()` Can be used to capture all possible signals and take an action when appropriate.

`doFinally()` executes after the Mono terminates.